# How can I create a line with small text below it as in contracts?

Tags: formatting, packages, forms

I would like to create a line with text below it as it can be seen often in contracts:

[image]

Ideally, that line would have a fillable element over it.

### Minimal Working Example

The best I could come up (which is much better than I've expected as I started writing this question!) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout
\usepackage{csquotes}       % nice quotes
\usepackage{parskip}        % I don't want indentation

\begin{document}
\section{Untermietvertrag}
Im Folgenden wird ein Untermietvertrag zwischen (nachfolgend \enquote{Hauptmieter} genannt)\\

\line(1,0){250}\\
\vspace{-0.3cm}
{\scriptsize Name, Anschrift}\\

und (nachfolgend \enquote{Untermieter} genannt)\\

\line(1,0){250}\\
\vspace{-0.3cm}
{\scriptsize Name, Anschrift}\\

geschlossen.
\end{document}
```

which renders to

[image]

This solution does not have fillable form elements at the over the lines.

Is there probably a package that helps when you want to write a contract? Or a document class?

Answer (score 2):

Not the prettiest, but:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout
\usepackage{csquotes}       % nice quotes
\usepackage{parskip}        % I don't want indentation

\begin{document}
\section{Untermietvertrag}
Im Folgenden wird ein Untermietvertrag zwischen (nachfolgend\enquote{Hauptmieter} genannt)\\

\def\platzhalter{Max Mustermann}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}}
   \platzhalter \\\hline
   \scriptsize Name, Anschrift \\
\end{tabular}

und (nachfolgend \enquote{Untermieter} genannt)\\

\def\platzhalter{}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}}
   \platzhalter \\\hline
   \scriptsize Name, Anschrift \\
\end{tabular}

geschlossen.
\end{document}
```

I put the `@{}` at before the column definition, because I like my fields better when their description is not indented. Instead of `\linewidth` you can put any width you like, thus creating "small input fileds".