# "Sign here" dotted line and names below

Tags: spacing, indentation

I'm trying to create a dotted line with a name below. It should be relatively simple. However, the dots appear indented with respect to the Name. They should be in line. I have tried `\hspace{}` before the names but it is not working.

Anyone know why?

[image: Names indented]

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\vspace{20mm}
................................ \newline
\hspace{1cm} Name one

\vspace{1cm}

................................ \newline
Name Person 2 

\vspace{1cm}

................................ \newline
Name Person 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: This question feels very duplicatish. There are [Dynamic signature/date line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48152/10478), [How can I create a line with small text below it as in contracts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173841/10478), [Dotted line instead of \hline in table environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169098/10478) and [Table Border Options](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10243/10478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is called indentation which is used in `article` for a new paragraph.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\vspace{20mm}
\noindent % local change
................................ \newline
Name one
\vspace{1cm}

\parindent0cm % global change
................................ \newline
Name Person 2
\vspace{1cm}

................................ \newline
Name Person 3
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar command for a declaration of integrity. What I did was to create a new command like this

```
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\makebox[4cm]{Wiener Neustadt,} \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}  \hfill\makebox[6cm]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\makebox[4cm]{} \makebox[3cm]{\centering Date}     \hfill\makebox[3.5cm][t]{Signature}%
}% These command is used to create the Date and Signature fields.
```

Then, the command `\SignatureAndDate{}` will produce the following output
[image: Signature fields]

Using that as a starting point, I created this command

```
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndName}[1]{%
    \makebox[6cm]{\hrulefill} %
    \par\makebox[1cm]{} \makebox[3cm]{\centering Name Family Name 1}\\
    \\
    \makebox[6cm]{\hrulefill} %
    \par\makebox[1cm]{} \makebox[3cm]{\centering Name Family Name 2}\\
    \\
    \makebox[6cm]{\hrulefill} %
    \par\makebox[1cm]{} \makebox[3cm]{\centering Name Family Name 3}\\
}
```

Which produced the output
[image]

I know that is not exactly what you want, and I gave you a solution for three given names that will be the same every time you use the command `\SignatureAndName`, but this is pretty much what I've learned to do in the short time I've been using LaTeX. I hope you can take it as a starting point and modify it to your needs.